# Interactive drop down box on excel

Tags: excel

I’m sure this is a really basic question for pro’s but I’m struggling to find the information online.

I’m creating a excel form which is a questionnaire. I want to create a drop down box where by selecting one of the outcome populated more boxes.

For example the drop down box will have the option for ‘house’ and ‘flat’. If you select ‘house’ it brings up further questions/text boxes relating houses and if you select ‘flat’ it brings up further questions/text boxes about flats

Can anyone help?

Comment: There're a bit of ways to do this, e.g., `indirect` references to named ranges with headers OR using a `combobox1_change()` event, but you would need to provide some more directive, and possible code, for your specific request.  As StackOverflow is not a code-for-you service, and has the intention of answering specific, direct questions, an open-ended request (or one with numerous answers, which would have a subjective nature) would be `Too broad` and viable for closing.

Comment: For a worksheet solution you could try https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html